# MySQL aliasing not working when subjoining

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two main tables: orders and PayPal transactions. I'm trying to get only the distinct values from my PayPal transactions table. Since there is no unique identifier in my transactions table I have tried to use a subquery to retrieve them.

The problem with my query is that MySQL doesn't recognize my aliases. Therefore, it gives me an Unknown column error.
/* SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'pp.Date' in 'field list' */

```
SELECT

pp.Date

FROM hub.orders o 

LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT p.transaction_of_interest AS ppID       
        FROM financial.paypal AS p
        GROUP BY p.transaction_of_interest
    ) AS pp ON pp.ppID = o.ex_trans_id
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  The query does not seem useful.  You have a `left join` and then are selecting only values from the second table.  Distinct values of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting `DATE` column from `PP` sub-query. If you include that column it will work as you would expect. If your result set multiplying because of `TRANSACTION_OF_INTEREST` values are not distinct then you should use a function on `P.DATE` like `MAX` to singularize yor `TRANSACTION_OF_INTEREST` values.

Which `PP.DATE` values you are need ? Is there any condition like last date or something ?

```
SELECT PP.DATE
  FROM HUB.ORDERS O
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT P.TRANSACTION_OF_INTEREST AS PPID,P.DATE
                    FROM FINANCIAL.PAYPAL AS P
        GROUP BY P.TRANSACTION_OF_INTEREST,P.DATE
    ) AS PP ON PP.PPID = O.EX_TRANS_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only refer to those fields via the derived table's alias that you included in the select list for the derived table. Since you did not include the `date` field in the select list, you cannot reference it.

You need to add the ¬Date¬ field to the select list in the subquery and to the `group by` clause as well.

```
SELECT

pp.Date

FROM hub.orders o 

LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT p.transaction_of_interest AS ppID, p.Date       
        FROM financial.paypal AS p
        GROUP BY p.transaction_of_interest, p.Date
    ) AS pp ON pp.ppID = o.ex_trans_id
```

Answer (score 0):

My best interpretation of your question is that you want distinct dates of PayPal transactions.

If you only want dates from the `paypal` table, doesn't this do what you want?

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.DATE     
FROM financial.paypal p;
```

If the dates come from the orders table, but you only want them for PayPal transactions, then `LEFT JOIN` is not appropriate:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.Date
FROM hub.orders o JOIN
     financial.paypal p
     ON pp.ppID = o.ex_trans_id
```

Comment: This was just an extract of the whole query. I have more than 30 columns  Using DISTINCT was an option I thought about but it won't fit my needs. Thank you.

Comment: @SPI . . . It is only possible to answer the quest that is being asked.  If you have a different question, then ask it as a *new* question.  Be sure you have a good explanation, sample data and desired results.